# Length of data to hash for PGP

Tags: hash, cryptography, implementation, pgp, dsa

I have finally managed to verify some simple PGP signed message blocks. However, I discovered that for some reason, my implementation limits me to verifying data that is 9-16 bytes long. no less. no more.

is there some instruction somewhere ([RFC4880](http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc4880.pdf) or elsewhere) that specifies how to deal with plaintext data of any length? maybe there is some sort of padding i missed? pkcs1?

I am pretty sure i formatted the data to hash properly, since the instructions in RFC 4880 sec 5.2.4 say for text documents, just replace all `\n` with `\r\n` and add a trailer. since my test values were single lines of data, nothing had to be replaced

all of these values are in base 10 unless otherwise noted:

```
// DSA public key values
p = 175466718616740411615640156350265486163809613514213656685227237159351776260193236923030228927905671867677337184318134702903960237546408302010360724274436019639502405323187799029742776686067449287558904042137172927936686590837020160292525250748155580652384740664931255981772117478967314777932252547256795892071
q = 809260232002608708872165272150356204306578772713
g = 127751900783328740354741342100721884490035793278553520238434722215554870393020469115393573782393994875216405838455564598493958342322790638050051759023658096740912555025710033120777570527002197424160086000659457154926758682221072408093235236853997248304424303705425567765059722098677806247252106481642577996274
y = 172935968966072909036304664996424500241381878537444332146572958203083745609400290814117451480512268901233962890933482206538294509037615827035398352528065134903071886710296983781453184598843331365336270501467458073523376152406987560592548479865116940266729198119357206749848310472131186772143408998928864559411
```

not working:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA1

abcd
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: BCPG v1.39

iFsEARECABsFAk/tB28UHGFiYyA8bWFrY21AYWFhLmNvbT4ACgkQMFIlRc933Ya2
RwCfdMyI08Iz0rDXVHOPlGA3s5Y9j/8An2He7+hHjWfGJNoOJT7gAxqJaoLo
=I2rT
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

data hashed (in hex): 6162636404011102001b05024fed076f141c616263203c6d616b636d406161612e636f6d3e04ff00000021

r = 666804200764671083282351405489424949903645052927
s = 558743769080942454889260816818443017172325925608

w =  702955297882281869313155599553522395227576660460 // s^-1 mod q
u1 = 190417717173929082607343542521304347388874234334
u2 = 306786785479358548892951170619047936651163362761
v = g^u1 * y^u2 % p % q = 737052148656331043521702886300418501784667890334

v != r
```

working:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA1

0123456789abcdef
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: BCPG v1.39

iFsEARECABsFAk/tCE0UHGFiYyA8bWFrY21AYWFhLmNvbT4ACgkQMFIlRc933YYG
IQCfercgPsXFnah6otgQdEMbv9OeCgIAnRIyOLirbqSlBugBT6Ex/Adz4+7L
=bzab
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

data hashed (in hex): 3031323334353637383961626364656604011102001b05024fed084d141c616263203c6d616b636d406161612e636f6d3e04ff00000021

r = 700580719365380086754774917458461236187098909186
s = 103881812262595813943381509986903840453887782603

w = 178510125628083028184051840492924307896586330444 // s^-1 mod q
u1 = 78831508775508876446567239486098677466912246622
u2 = 572875590470993668032596348682349224460207395691
v = g^u1 * y^u2 % p % q = 700580719365380086754774917458461236187098909186

v == r
```

what data did i not include in the hash / what did i do wrong?

EDIT: here is the public key as requested, even though the relevant values have been posted already)

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: BCPG v1.39
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=sStS
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Comment: can you put here the "-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----" block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't got enough time to look up the details, but I would guess that you're applying (or not applying) padding correctly. That would cause the right result to come up for some input lengths, but not for others.

I guess I'll look into this more, but I wanted to get something in under the bounty wire :)

**Edit**: Ok, found an error. Not sure why you're getting it, but if it's fixed, then the right answer comes out. In your not-working example, you calculate `w` (s^-1 mod q) as

```
w =  702955297882281869313155599553522395227576660460 // s^-1 mod q
```

but I get

```
w =  702955297882281869313155599553522395227576660458
```

off by 2! Really, really close values though. And it can be shown that mine is right:

```
s * your_w mod q = 308227306159276200906356361486529830038073078504
s * my_w mod q = 1
```

If you plug in this w value, you then get

```
u1 = 536931432138658080437983667536052790245747416035
u2 = 591698847955233800072578903940910445457030802333
v = (g^u1 * y^u2) % p % q = 666804200764671083282351405489424949903645052927
r == v
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: lol how did that happen? time to dig through my arbitrary precision integer code

Comment: And this is just for learning, right? It seems like I should repeat the ever-vital "*don't ever implement crypto yourself*" warning.